# How to colour the view behind table view in xcode ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I was making an ios app in xcode made a table view and added an image above it in the view controller and coloured both of them red both view and table view but when i drag down the table view till the end the view behind comes white instead of red. Can you tell me how to fix it Thnx in Advance;)

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import PINRemoteImage
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
    var data = [DataModel]()
        @IBOutlet weak var one: UIImageView!



    @IBOutlet weak var mytable: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {


        doSetup()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 138/255, green: 56/255, blue: 48/255, alpha: 1.0)

        mytable.dataSource = self
        mytable.delegate = self

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func doSetup(){


        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        //ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["post_text":" Nami ","imageUrl" : ""])
        ref.child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let newData = snapshot.value as! [String:String]

            let post_text = newData["post_text"]
            let imageUrl = newData["imageUrl"]

            let converted = DataModel(post_text: post_text, imageUrl: imageUrl)

            self.data.append(converted)

            self.mytable.reloadData()

            self.one.pin_setImage(from: URL(string : "https://otaku-w9pxf76zfsktmx3e.stackpathdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Luffy.png"))


        })

    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

        let nth_data = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.posttext.text = nth_data.post_text
        cell.posttext.textColor = .white
        cell.myimage.pin_setImage(from: URL(string: nth_data.imageUrl!))
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 138/255, green: 56/255, blue: 48/255, alpha: 1.0)
        return (cell)
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Before you ask for help, post your code.

Comment: Just give your tableview and cell clear color. This will solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want red background below all the subviews, place that inside your `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` function:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

**UPD**

In this case you can either set `myTable.backgroundColor` to be red, or set  `self.view.backgroundColor` to red having `myTable` and each of the cells' colors set to `UIColor.clear`

Comment: i did this thing but i didnt help

Comment: @Vladim how to do so?

Comment: @DevTech By editing your question. there is an edit button under it

Comment: Did so thnx now can u help? :)

Comment: @DevTech have you tried to set you `tableView.backgroundColor` to red?

Comment: @DevTech glad you've sorted this out. Please don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Can u tell how to do so?

Comment: btw I have another question can u help me with that i just posted it

Answer (score 1):

When you run your project, use this to debug view. Believe it or not, it's very useful.
[image]

Comment: thats really helpful thnx